# Can't convert Map<String, AttributeValue> (DynamoDB) to POJO if use annotation @Builder

Tags: java-8, aws-java-sdk, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

I'm trying convert Map<String, AttributeValue> to POJO. I do it like that:

```
new DynamoDBMapper(awsConfiguration.amazonDynamoDbClient()).marshallIntoObject(MyClass.class, myMap);
```

---

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "myClass")
@Data
public class MyClass{

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String jobId;
    private String applicationId;
}
```

@Data - annotations from Lombok.
And it works fine.

But if I add annotation @Builder, I get exception

```
Method threw 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException' exception.

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "myClass")
@Data
@Builder
   public class MyClass{

    @DynamoDBHashKey
        private String jobId;
        private String applicationId;
}
```

How can I solve that problem? Thank you.

Comment: Pastre the whole stacktrace, not just its first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding: @AllArgsConstructor and @NoArgsConstructor annotations to the class.